# How many permutations of 160 outputs from binomial B(1, p) if p varies?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

I apologise for the question title if it's not accurate.  I've spent a long time trying to formulate this.  Let me try to explain by example...

Assume a binomial distribution like B(1, p) where there is a binary choice of 1 or 0 as output, and p is the probability of the output being 1.  Now assume we generate 160 outputs. This is my question: I'm interested in how many permutations (order matters) of the 160 output numbers there are in a general case where p can vary.

So for B(1, 0.5) on average, we can have 160!/(80! * 80!) permutations of ones and zeros which is ~ 10^47. I get this formula from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/452/394771.

What would the mean number of permutations be for 160 outputs from the general case of B(1, p) if p is a variable and not equal to 0.5?

Another example:

Take p = 0.1, and get 160 outcomes from distribution B(1, 0.1).  On the average, you'll get 16 ones, and therefore the mean number of unique permutations is 160! / (16! x 144!) or 4.1^21.  What's the general formula for any p?  My formula collapses for long decimal values of p where the binomial mean isn't an integer such as p = 0.557, giving a mean of 89.12.  The factorial of 89.12 is tricky for me.

I feel exactly what I want but can't express it clearly, so please bear with me.  I'm only an engineer :-(

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.  Are you asking for the expected number of distinct sequences of zeroes and ones?

Comment: @awkward Yes, related to the value of p.  If p is small, you mainly get zeros and that reduces the number of distinct permutations.  Doesn't it?  Eg. If p where such that the binomial mean was 1, you could only have 160 possible permutations in 160 trials.

Comment: @awkward And of course the mean isn't always an integer, so the standard combination /permutation formulae don't work with their factorial terms.

Comment: I'm not sure I  understand the problem statement.  In all cases except when $p=0$ or $p=1$, all sequences of 160 ones and zeroes are possible, of which there are $2^{160}$ possibilities.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @awkward I've added another example to the question in a for-lone hope that it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Take p = 0.1, and get 160 outcomes from distribution B(1, 0.1). On the average, you'll get 16 ones, and therefore the mean number of unique permutations is 160! / (16! x 144!) or 4.1^21. What's the general formula for any p?

Let $(X_1,...,X_n)$ be the sequence of $n$ independent random variables, each distributed as $\text{Binomial}(1,p),$ and let $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$ (which equals the number of $1$s in the sequence).

Let $A_n$ be the number of different ways in which to arrange the random binary sequence $(X_1,...,X_n)$. (In combinatorics these are called *arrangements*, whereas the term *permutations* refers to sequences *all* of whose elements are distinct.) This is given by the following binomial coefficient:

$$A_n = \binom{n}{S_n}.$$

We may now consider the expected value of $A_n$:

$$\begin{align}E[A_n]&=E\,\binom{n}{S_n}\\[2ex]
&=\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\,\binom{n}{k}\,P(S_n=k)\\[2ex]
&=\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\,\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\[2ex]
&=\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\,\binom{n}{k}^2\,p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\[2ex]
&= \ _2F_1\left(-n;-n;1;{p\over 1-p}\right)\,(1-p)^n
\end{align}$$

where $_2F_1$ is the [ordinary hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), which in this case is a polynomial in $p$. (To get this and results below, I used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+binomial(n,k)%5E2+p%5Ek+(1-p)%5E(n-k),+k%3D0..n).)

Note that $E[A_n]$, as a function of $p$, is maximized by $p={1\over 2}$:
$$\left\{E[A_n]\right\}_{p={1\over 2}}=2^n{\left(n-{1\over 2}\right)!\over n!\,\sqrt{\pi}}\sim 2^n\sqrt{{1\over n\,\pi}}.$$

**NB**: Instead of computing the *mean number of arrangements*, $E[A_n]=E\,\binom{n}{S_n}$, you computed the *number of arrangements of a sequence having the mean number of $1$s*, i.e., $\binom{n}{E[S_n]}=\binom{n}{np}$, when $np$ is an integer; then you were confused by what to do in case $np$ is not an integer. Although I think $E[A_n]$ is probably the quantity you want to look at, nevertheless the quantity you were using can be naturally extended to non-integers, using the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):

$$\binom{n}{E[S_n]}=\binom{n}{np}={n!\over (np)!\,(n(1-p))!}$$
where $x!$ is extended to all real $x$ except negative integers, by the *definition*
$$x!::=\Gamma(x+1).$$
This too is maximized by $p={1\over 2}$, for which its asymptotic behavior differs from before by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$:
$$\left\{\binom{n}{E[S_n]}\right\}_{p={1\over 2}}=\binom{n}{n\over 2}\sim 2^n\sqrt{{2\over n\,\pi}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks.  Now I just need to figure out how to use the Gamma function for non integer ps.

Comment: @PaulUszak - On the web you'll find plenty of numerical algorithms/formulas for that (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Versions_suitable_for_calculators)).

Comment: @PaulUszak - But, be warned: If $E\,\binom{n}{S_n}$ is really what you want, then $\binom{n}{E[S_n]}$ *might* be a very poor approximation of it -- that would need careful examination. See the answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70490/taking-the-expectation-of-taylor-series-especially-the-remainder) for some discussion.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I finally understand the problem.

If you draw a sample of $160$ independent random numbers, where the probability of drawing a one is $p$ and the probability of drawing a zero is $1-p$, then the probability that you will have $k$ ones (hence $160-k$ zeroes) in the sample is $\binom{160}{k} p^k (1-p)^{160-k}$.  The number of possible sequences of $k$ ones and $160-k$ zeroes is $\binom{160}{k}$.  So the expected number of possible sequences of length $160$ which could be generated by permuting the original $160$ numbers is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{160} \binom{160}{k}^2 p^k (1-p)^{160-k}$$

Maybe this expression can be simplified, but I don't see how right now.

Comment: Er, isn't the number of expected ones simply 160p for a binomial distribution?

Comment: @PaulUszak Yes, the number of expected ones is $160p$, but to find the expected number of possible permutations you need the probability of getting $k$ ones.  The expected value alone is not sufficient.  Assuming, as always, that I have correctly understood the problem.